Why my Python Tkinter button command function not working?
I am learning Tkinter GUI and trying basic things.
I am trying this Button command function example and coped/pasted the code into VSCode.
When run, it showed up fine but the Entry form is not updating when buttons clicked as it should. Someone else tried and said it works for him. Why is it?
Here is the screenshot on my Macbook

I just tried it on my Windows system and it works fine. Please edit your question and post the exact code that you are using.

It is better to copy the code into the question instead of link of code.

@OldBoy55 , my code is exactly the same as shown in the link.

Are you in dark-mode? You're putting white text one a white background. The text is there, you just can't see it. Try selecting it and then it will show up. At least, that's what happens on this macbook!  :-)  Remove the 'bg="white"' from the entry widget. Have fun!
